# appending a list to a set of a result (dict)

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe

I am preparing a code for some work. I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
# initialize list of lists 
data = [['1', 10, 50, 'ev', 'CA'], ['2', 15, 40, 'ev', 'CA'], ['3', 14, 60, 'ev', 'CN']] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['person_id', 'kwh', 'distance', 'type', 'country']) 
  
# print dataframe. 
df
```

And I loop over each row of `df` in order to calculate something based on one column of dataframe.

```
dics = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # Retrieve person-ID
    person = df['person_id'].tolist()
    if row['type'] == 'ev':
        cm.array.loc['Small','BEV','electricity consumption',:] = [[row['kwh_km']]]
        ---Some very long codes---
        output = results.sel(impact_category='cc', year=2020, size='Small', value=0)\
        .to_dataframe('impact') #selecting only cc
        output_dict = dict(zip(['ex', 'ne', 'ec',
                      'ma', 'gl', 'eo', 'po', 
                      'es', 'ro'], output.impact)) 
        dics.append({person: {output_dict}})   #assigning person id to each result in a dict
```

Problem: i tried to get a list `person_id` and at the end of code, I tried to create a dict of result in `output_dict`.
Now that I have a list and a dict, i want to append them in the `dics`, but it did not work for me. It threw an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-da106d6e5fc2> in <module>
     19                       'ma', 'gl', 'eo', 'po',
     20                       'es', 'ro'], output.impact))
---> 21         dics.append({person: {output_dict}})

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I expect the output to be like below (example): `output_dict` according to each `person_id` in dataframe.

```
[{'1':{'ex': 0.0,
  'ne': 0.0,
  'ec': 0.0,
  'ma': 0.0,
  'gl': 0.0,
  'eo': 0.0,
  'po': 0.0,
  'es': 0.0,
  'ro': 0.0}},
 {'2':{'ex': 0.0,
  'ne': 0.0,
  'ec': 0.0,
  'ma': 0.0,
  'gl': 0.0,
  'eo': 0.0,
  'po': 0.0,
  'es': 0.0,
  'ro': 0.0}},
 {'3':{'ex': 0.0,
  'ne': 0.0,
  'ec': 0.0,
  'ma': 0.0,
  'gl': 0.0,
  'eo': 0.0,
  'po': 0.0,
  'es': 0.0,
  'ro': 0.0}}]
```

I am sorry that I removed some codes in "Some very long code". Your help and advice are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are creating appending an id of a person to a set of a result, rather than an id to a result.

The curly braces around the `output_dict` means you are creating a set of the dictionary. Since dictionaries are not hashable python raises the error. If you want to keep `dics` as a list of single entry dictionaries removing those curly braces should resolve your issue.

```
dics.append({person: output_dict})
```

However, it will probably server you better make `dics` as dictionary so you can store all your ids and results in the same place like this:

```
{'1':{'ex': 0.0,
  'ne': 0.0,
  'ec': 0.0,
  'ma': 0.0,
  'gl': 0.0,
  'eo': 0.0,
  'po': 0.0,
  'es': 0.0,
  'ro': 0.0},
 '2':{'ex': 0.0,
  'ne': 0.0,
  'ec': 0.0,
  'ma': 0.0
  'gl': 0.0,
  'eo': 0.0,
  'po': 0.0,
  'es': 0.0,
  'ro': 0.0)
  ...
}
```

This will allow you to more simply pull out results. In you initial attempt to pull out the results for the persion of id 1 you would need to find that entry in the list then pull the data out of the dictionary:

```py
for data in dics:
    if data.keys()[0] == "1":
        result = data["1"]
        # do something with result
```

This is very verbose and slow. But by storing them as a single dictionary tyou can immediately access them:

```
result = dics["1"]
```

```py
dics = dict()

# some code here...
dics[person] = output_dict
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but when I use indices, it throw another error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`.

Comment: oh you wanted a list of one -entry dictionaries? Then append without the curly braces will work fine. I'll update teh answer

Comment: yes, but actually, I did try that earlier and got invalid syntax. That is why I add two curly braces

Comment: But if i remove one pair of curly brace, the error remains : `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

Comment: You have person defined as a `list` which is unhashable, convert that to a single id or other hashable type. A  dictionary is basically just a `set` whose elements have another associated value. The dictionary keys must be hashable

Comment: I did try to convert it using tuple method `some_dict = {tuple(person)}`. Then I have `dics = []` and `dics.append({some_dict: output_dict})`. I got an error of unhashable type set.

Comment: Because sets are also unhashable, collections generally will never be hashable. Ether create you own class and implement the `__hash__` magic method or boil the person down to just their id as you have shown in your example of expected output in your question

Comment: okay, i will try it now. Anyway, I appreciate your time and answers. Your suggestions are very helpful.

Comment: I found a solution, but not really fast if i work with bigger dataframe (>20000 observations)
I changed the code as follow:
`dics = dict()` before `for i, row in df.iterrows():` and added `person = row['person_id']` before `if row['type'] == 'ev':` and finally I followed your suggestion using `dics[person] = output_dict`. I got the result as i expect. Thank you